# BigDecimal.intValue() returns Unexpected Number

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I'm running into a strange java bug using the intValue() from the BigDecimal class.

I'm starting with a value of 3300028000.

When I call the following code:

```
int i = d.intValue();
```

it returns: -994939296

Any ides as to why this would happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you try to fit this number into an int variable, it overflows, since the int type in Java has 32 bits, ergo an int variable can store values that range from −2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.

To store the value of your BigInteger, you have to use a long variable. Try this:

```
long value = d.longValue();
```

Comment: `longValue` risks the same problem, FYI, it just needs bigger values before you start seeing the overflow.

Comment: Correct. To store your value in a long variable, you need to make sure it won't be bigger than 64 bits signed. If your BigInteger value can and will be bigger than 64 bits, you should keep it into a BigValue object.

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo. I meant BigInteger.

Answer (score 4):

An int can't hold a value that big, so it overflows. Try using a long.

Answer (score 2):

What would you like it to return? :)

As described in the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#intValue%28%29):

> if the resulting "BigInteger" is too big to fit in an int, only the
>   low-order 32 bits are returned

[intValueExact](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#intValueExact%28%29), on the other hand, would throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

You should really read [Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#intValue%28%29) before blaming it:

> Converts this BigDecimal to an int. This conversion is analogous to
>   the narrowing primitive conversion from double to short as defined in
>   section 5.1.3 of The Java™ Language Specification: any fractional part
>   of this BigDecimal will be discarded, and if the resulting
>   "BigInteger" is too big to fit in an int, only the low-order 32 bits
>   are returned. Note that this conversion can lose information about the
>   overall magnitude and precision of this BigDecimal value as well as
>   return a result with the opposite sign.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you need the int value of a BigDecimal but the class BigDecimal contains lots of methods to fit your request.

```
compareTo 
add 
substract 
multiply 
divide
```

etc..

I would work with BigDecimal itself. Sooner or later; Converting the BigDecimal type to other primitive types will end up with an error. Cuz all of them has a limit.